# How can I take the user to a new page, along with some variables, using Javascript/jQuery, without causing a URI Too Large error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript/jQuery, I need to take the user to a new page when a button is clicked, and also send along a bunch of variables to the new page. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
location.href=window.location.href + '/new_note?id='+$('#note_id').val()+'&note_subnotes='+encodeURIComponent(window.JSON.stringify(sub_notes))
```

This works okay, but the problem is that `sub_notes` is an array of hashes, which can get pretty large. If I have more than a few hashes in the array, I get this error:

```
Request-URI Too Large
WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
```

So obviously the URI is too big. How can I do this without running into this problem? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just curious - you're saying when a button is clicked...why not a normal `<form>` POST?

Comment: @Nick Craver - It initially was a form POST, but I couldn't work out how/if it was possible to add the sub_notes array to the parameters of the form, since it's a Javascript object and the form is comprised of HTML elements

Comment: You can send a JSON serialized string via POST as well (and let the server put the string (or relevant variables) back in the page).

Comment: @Marcel Korpel - Thanks for your comment. Any chance you could give me an idea/point me in the right direction to work out how to do that?

Comment: @ben: add an `<input type="hidden" name="sub_notes">` to your form, and `POST` the serialized JSON as its value

Comment: @Marcel @Eric - I ended up using your suggestions. If either of you submit an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Eric already posted an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Use a cookie for your long string. Stock the data into a cookie, and get it on the next page.

Comment: Cookies are also limited in size.

Answer (score 1):

You could send the data using POST or GET. I'd imagine post can handle much more data, with it being used to upload files and all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry to ask for more help, but do you know how I can send a javascript array using POST/GET that actually takes the user to the target address? I know how to do $.get & $.post, but AFAIK these return data that is then acted upon in the current page.

Comment: you could do a callback on the $.post, that brings your user to the page as soon as the data has been submitted

Comment: so the data would have to be stored server side in the post, then retrieved from the server on the next page?

Comment: `GET` is exactly what @ben is doing. `POST` is the way to go, if you don't think cookies are appropriate. However, the `POST`-ed data is *not retrievable* via javascript. You'll need to `echo` it with PHP.

Comment: *facepalm" of course @ben was using get - my apologies! And yes, as @Eric says, you will need to use PHP to fetch the `POST`ed data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sending page:

```
var form = $('<form>')
    .attr('action', url)
    .attr('method', 'POST')
    .append($('<input type="hidden">')
        .attr({
            'id': 'data',
            'name': 'data',
            'value': JSON.stringify(data)
        })
    )
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .submit()
    .remove();
```

(hooray for jQuery chaining)

#### Receiving page (PHP required):

```
var data = <?php echo @$_POST['data'] or 'null' ?>
```